# How to disable the "undefined method for nil:NilClass" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of code like `current_user.articles` or `current_user.name` in my controllers and views. Obviously, when there is no current user, this leads to an error. I could write something like `current_user && current_user.articles` all the time, but that's repetitive.

Is there some way to disable this error message and just return a warning if a method is called on current_user, but current_user doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&` before accessing to any object method or attribute to avoid errors. This way, if the object is nil, all chain after `&` will be avoided and result will be nil.

```rb
current_user&.name # User name if current_user exists, nil otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling the error (which does not seem like a particularly super awesome idea), consider using either the ruby safe navigation operator, `&.` or `.try`.

Please be aware that some folks ([here's](https://www.theguild.nl/5-reasons-not-to-use-safe-navigation-operators/) an example) view this as code smell. But, IMO, less smelly than disabling the `NoMethodError`.